# Why is trace not preserved in tensordot

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, tensordot

I am trying to take a tensor product of three density matrices and express it in the product basis. Each of these matrices have trace 1 and theoretically, the product matrix should as well. But doing this in numpy seems to have some unintended effects. Even reshaping the intermediary array to a 2d form gives the same answer.

```py
In [31]: rho1
Out[31]: 
array([[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.2, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.3, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.4]])

In [32]: np.trace(rho1)
Out[32]: 1.0

In [33]: rho2
Out[33]: 
array([[0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0.2, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.2]])

In [34]: np.trace(rho2)
Out[34]: 1.0

In [35]: rho3
Out[35]: 
array([[0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])

In [36]: np.trace(rho3)
Out[36]: 1.0

In [37]: rho = np.tensordot(rho1, np.tensordot(rho2, rho3, axes=0), axes=0)

In [38]: np.trace(rho.reshape(125, 125))
Out[38]: 0.010000000000000002

In [39]: rho = np.tensordot(rho1, np.tensordot(rho2, rho3, axes=0).reshape(25,25), axes=0)

In [40]: np.trace(rho.reshape(125, 125))
Out[40]: 0.010000000000000002
```

I can't really find any bug in this code, so I feel I am misunderstanding how tensordot and reshape work. But I didn't really get anything from the docs. Can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

I guess that you're looking for the kronecker tensor product: `np.kron()`:

```
rho = np.kron(rho1, np.kron(rho2, rho3))
```

And this time:

```
np.trace(rho)
Out[22]: 1.0000000000000002
```

**Details:**

Why your solution does not work ?

Because `np.reshape()` do not reshape your array with the "right" dimension order, you could eventually permute some dimension to get the desired result:

```
rho = np.moveaxis(np.tensordot(rho1, np.moveaxis(np.tensordot(rho1, rho2, axes=0),[0,1,2,3],[0,2,3,1]).reshape((5,5)), axes=0),[0,1,2,3],[0,2,3,1]).reshape((125,125))
```

Will output the correct result, but since `np.kron` exist, it is a bit overkill.

Actually you think that `np.tensordot(rho1,rho2,axes=0)` is equivalent to:

```
np.einsum('ik,jl',rho1,rho2)
```

But in fact `np.tensordot(rho1,rho2,axes=0)` compute:

```
np.einsum('ij,kl',rho1,rho2)
```

So another way to get the right answer will be to use:

```
np.einsum('ik,jl',rho1,rho2).reshape(5,5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the `np.kron` suggestion! The reason I used [tensordot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) was because its documentation says that it gives the tensor product when axes=0 is given and this is apparently a 'common use case'. So it should also be giving the tensor product but perhaps there are some intricacies involved.

Comment: Yeah, but `tensordot(...,axes=0)` keep the dimension of the second argument, so it is indeed the tensor product, but for your need it messed up with the order of the dimensions. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The tensordot docs does say that axes=0 gives a tensor product:

```
axes = 0 : tensor product :math:`a\otimes b`,
```

an outer product of the arrays.  But you have to pay attention to how the resulting dimensions are arranged.

But it says:

```
The shape of the result consists of the non-contracted axes of the
first tensor, followed by the non-contracted axes of the second.
```

With `axes=0`, it in effect creates `rho2[:,:,None]` and `rho3[:,None,:]` and does the sum-of-products on the normal `dot` axes.

```
In [37]: x=np.tensordot(rho2, rho3, 0)
In [38]: x.shape
Out[38]: (5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Comparing it to `einsum` with default 'ijkl' output:

```
In [40]: y=np.einsum('ij,kl',rho2,rho3)
In [41]: y.shape
Out[41]: (5, 5, 5, 5)
In [42]: np.allclose(x,y)
Out[42]: True
```

or the `dot` equivalent:

```
In [44]: z=np.dot(rho2[:,:,None],rho3[:,None,:])
In [45]: np.allclose(x,z)
Out[45]: True
```

The first 2 dimensions come from `rho2`.

If what you really want was the `kron`, we have to first transpose the dimensions, interleaving ones from the 2 arrays:

```
In [46]: K=np.kron(rho2,rho3)
In [47]: K.shape
Out[47]: (25, 25)
In [48]: np.trace?
In [49]: np.allclose(x.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(25,25),K)
Out[49]: True
```

Testing the trace:

```
In [50]: K.trace()
Out[50]: 1.0
```

The same thing with `einsum`.  Note the order of indices:

```
In [53]: np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl',rho2,rho3).reshape(25,25).trace()
Out[53]: 1.0
```

Another way to look at this is extract the 2d diagonal values from the 4d array:

```
In [60]: j = np.arange(5); i=j[:,None]
In [61]: x[i,i,j,j]
Out[61]: 
array([[0.1, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
In [62]: _.sum()
Out[62]: 1.0
```

Simply reshaping `x`, puts these values on the diagonal:

```
In [63]: x[i,j,i,j]
Out[63]: 
array([[0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.1, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
```

Equivalently with a 2 step trace:

```
In [75]: x.trace(0,0,1)
Out[75]: 
array([[0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]])
In [76]: x.trace(0,0,1).trace()
Out[76]: 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

np.tensordot is not a tensor product, but rather a dot product for tensors. The tensor prouct is analoguous to an outer product.